# How to add another column to SELECT DISTINCT query for other columns?

Tags: sqlite

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE APmeasure 
(id_APmeasure INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT 
 , RSSI TEXT, TimeOfMeasure DATETIME
 , BSSID TEXT, id_APm INTEGER NOT NULL 
 , FOREIGN KEY (id_APm) REFERENCES APTable (id_Ap) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

I want to make a query which would give me distinct results of `TimeOfMeasure` and `BSSID`, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TimeOfMeasure, BSSID 
FROM APmeasure 
WHERE "condition"
```

But that would retrieve me the other columns on the table, related to the DISTINCT query.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Perform distinct/grouping operation,
2. Join to result of distinct/grouping operation...

Something like:

```
SELECT [whichever columns you want]
  FROM APmeasure 
       JOIN (
           SELECT TimeOfMeasure, BSSID 
             FROM APmeasure 
            WHERE [condition]
         GROUP BY TimeOfMeasure, BSSID
       ) x
       ON x.TimeOfMeasure = APmeasure.TimeOfMeasure
   AND x.BSSID = APmeasure.BSSID
       [any other joins you need]
```

Comment: This retrieves repetitive values of BSSID in the same TimeOfMeasure, I want DISTINCT..

Comment: `group by`, like `distinct`, is fully capable of producing the result you request. Here is a link to a similar problem (not exactly the same but similar); the author tried a couple of approaches and chose the technique shown above: http://poeticcode.wordpress.com/2008/02/20/sqlite-join-and-group-by-vs-group-by-and-join/